# Graph Api calling for Drive returns generalException

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I've created a powershell script to call and create Ms Team channels, folders and subfolders using the Graph API. The following code is an example of how I call for data.

```
$AzTeamsAccessToken = Get-AccessToken -ClientID $ClientId -ClientSecret $SecretValueText -TenantName $TenantName
$apiUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/$GroupID/drive/root/children"
$Output = Invoke-RestMethod -Headers @{Authorization = "Bearer $($AzTeamsAccessToken)"} -Uri $apiUrl -Method GET
```

We're receiving the following error when calling for /groups/$groupid/drive

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {
  "error": {
    "code": "generalException",
    "message": "An unspecified error has occurred.",
    "innerError": {
      "date": "2021-01-27T10:12:32",
      "request-id": "72a76c26-0634-4219-8bd3-46f4b52c855b",
      "client-request-id": "72a76c26-0634-4219-8bd3-46f4b52c855b"
    }
  }
}
```

We're using Application permission type with the following permissions granted by a global admin;

- Files.Read.All,
- Files.ReadWrite.All,
- Sites.Read.All,
- Sites.ReadWrite.All

It also has the rights to call for group details and to edit them.

This errormessage does not occur for all groups, most work accordingly, however all groups were made in the same way with the same owners.

Edit:
When calling /groups/$groupid/drive via Graph Explorer the error does not occur.

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the issue but I was unable to get the error. Try it in POSTMAN or a Curl command and see how to goes. Looks like an issue with the token.

Comment: Does the above helped?